# Galois group of a subextension is a subgroup of the Galois group of the extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{5}$ be the separable closure of $\mathbb{F}_{5}$ and let $G=G(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{5}/\mathbb{F}_{5})$ be its Galois group.

Say we pick a finite subextension of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{5}/\mathbb{F}_{5}$ such as $\mathbb{F}_{5}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{F}_{5}$, which has Galois group $\{\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2}\}$, where $\varphi_{1}$ is identity and $\varphi_{2}$ is conjugation.

How can I see this Galois group inside the big Galois group $G$?

I'm supposed to see it as a quotient of $G$ by some subgroup or simply as a subgroup of $G$? This is still very confusing. Sorry if the question is so easy.

Comment: Do you know the main theorem of Galois theory ?

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't we associate to the subextension $\mathbb{F}_{5}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{F}_{5}$ the subgroup of automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{5}$ that fix $\mathbb{F}_{5}(\sqrt{2})$? Where does the Galois group of the extension itself appear in the history?

Comment: Is it the quotient of $G$ by the subgroup associated with $\mathbb{F}_{5}(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: In a word : yes. Examine closely the part of your course where the theorem is stated, it's very probably there.

Comment: So far, I've only used the correspondence part of the theorem and probably forgot about the rest. Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that the Galois group $G(\overline{\Bbb F}_5/\Bbb F_5)$ is topologically generated by the Frobenius automorphism of $\overline{\Bbb F}_5$, which sends any element $\alpha$ to $\alpha^5$? You can think of it as an infinite cyclic group, but completed with respect to a certain topology.

Calling the Frobenius automorphism $\mathbf f$, its square $\mathbf f^2$ (defined by $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^{25}$) generates a subgroup of index two. That’s the subgroup you’re looking for.